# Open PopUp if come

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to have open pop-up with login form when user come from other site, and is redirected.
Lets say user come from https:www.asd.com/profile but hes not logged in, so hes redirected to main page www.asd.com but with open popup login form.

My login form div

```
    <div id="zaloguj">
    <div class="zamknij"></div>
    <div>
        <div class="null"></div>
        <div class="logincontent">
            <div class="logindiv">
                <div class="login-logo"></div>
                <form action="/login/index.php" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="username" size="20"/>
                    <input type="password" name="password" size="15"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Zaloguj się" /> </form>
                <div class="opis opis-forgot">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How i can check and perform some actions if the user was redirected?

Comment: do you really need to check if he's redirected? I think you need to check if he's logged in and that's a job for back-end  (for example PHP)

Comment: Yes, im coding in php aswell. That would be also a good solution, but i need to do it as i described

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if JS can solve this, (might be with cookies, but I'm skeptic about that). I offer you a PHP solution:

```
<?PHP // set this in your main page
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['notRedirected'] = true;
?>
```

in your page you can get directed to you can check if session variable is set *true*:

```
<?PHP
    session_start();
    if( $_SESSION['notRedirected'] ) {
        //...
    }
?>
```

Comment: Oh, it works! I've added only session_unset(); to purge session after statement is done :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I try to understand, you want to redirect to homepage if user not login right.
If so, you can use javascript. I am not good with that but I will try to explain the logic:
If you using PHP as backend, you can use SESSION/CACHE function to know if user loged in or not
- on the profile page:

```
//check if user login or not
function status(){
if(userstatus==notLogedin){
window.location.replace = "http://www.asd.com?status=notlogin";
}
else{
//run page normally}
}    
status();
```

on homepage, your js will be:

```
if(status==notlogin){ //you have to take parameter from URL
callPopupLogin();  //call your login form on pop up
}
else{
//run homepage normally
}
```